# Synchronizing two sensors on uart, make one receiver and one transmitter

Tags: uart

I need to make a transmitter and receiver with each specifically transmitting and receiving a signal. I am using two SRF-02 sensors, one is the designated transmitter, the other the receiver.

My issue is that the receiver is not currently able to pick up the reading, reason being that the receiver has no idea of when the startbyte is incoming or when the stop byte comes.

Can i send the receiver a start byte when i activate the transmitter and send an end byte for when the signal is received?

Comment: Please provide links to this sensor. Please post your code. I'm going to close this question as "unclear what you are asking". Feel free to edit it with new information. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!